# The variable is not incrementing properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, increment

I have a webpage that examines users with some questions.
When a person answers one question, it hides and another one comes up.
I came up with a code that uses incrementation but it doesnt work.
I also wrote exactly the same thing just using numbers instead of incrementing variable and it works perfect. What is the difference?

This code works:

```js
$(".questionBox" + 0 + " .answerButton").click(function() {
  $(".questionBox" + 0).hide();
  $(".questionBox" + 1).show();
  $(".answerButton").hide();
});

$(".questionBox" + 1 + " .answerButton").click(function() {
  $(".questionBox" + 1).hide();
  $(".questionBox" + 2).show();
  $(".answerButton").hide();
});

$(".questionBox" + 2 + " .answerButton").click(function() {
  $(".questionBox" + 2).hide();
  $(".questionBox" + 3).show();
  $(".answerButton").hide();
});
```

But this one NOT:

```js
let i = 0;

$(".questionBox" + i + " .answerButton").click(function() {
  $(".questionBox" + i).hide();
  i++;
  $(".questionBox" + i).show();
  $(".answerButton").hide();
});
```

Comment: Where is your `for`-loop?

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl There is no loop. The script is included in html and it gets triggered on click

Comment: How do you then apply it to multiple if only one is listed? You need a `for` loop, s this code only get executed once, or you need to wrap this in a method and then call it at the end after the click again to apply it to the next bit.

Comment: Your code is too-coupled. Try to remove hard-coded classes. You can easily make this more dynamic and easier to read.

Comment: Maybe this link will help you: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/iterating/

Comment: @somethinghere User gets questionBox0, when ha clicks answer, it hides, variable gets incremented and questionBox1 shows up. Then he clicks again in the questionBox1 and it hides and again and again. Is it really wrong?

Comment: The second click doesnt even go inside the .click function

Comment: Yeah the issue is that your code only gets executed _once_ when your page loads. It attaches the click, shows and hides the question/answer, increements a variable, and that's it, that's where your instructions end. Your code needs to then apply clicking the next answer again, so you either need a loop or a recursive function (better to go for a loop). The incremented variable never gets used again.

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to keep track of an index variable. Just declare some indices at `data` attributes. You can advance to the next question by getting the parent `.question-box` of the `.answer-button` and call `.next()` to go to the next sibling and show it.

```js
$('.question-box').not(':first-child').hide();

$('.answer-button').on('click', function() {
  const $parent = $(this.closest('.question-box'));
  const index = parseInt($parent.data('index'), 10);
  const $next = $parent.hide().next();
  if ($next.length !== 0) {
    $next.show();
  } else {
    console.log('Done!');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="questions">
  <div class="question-box" data-index="0">
    <h2>Question 1</h2>
    <button class="answer-button">Answer</button>
  </div>

  <div class="question-box" data-index="1">
    <h2>Question 2</h2>
    <button class="answer-button">Answer</button>
  </div>

  <div class="question-box" data-index="2">
    <h2>Question 3</h2>
    <button class="answer-button">Answer</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to solve your issue using the incrementing variable, but it's definitely worth thinking in @MrPolywhirls answer above. I'm just adding these to show the issue you are seeing with your compacted code. The first example is to call a method to instantiate the first on, and then as questions get answered you want to instantiate the next ones. That would look something like this:

```
let i = 0;

function applyToQuestionBox(){

  $(".questionBox" + i + " .answerButton").click(function() {
    $(".questionBox" + i).hide();
    i++;
    $(".questionBox" + i).show();
    $(".answerButton").hide();
    // The answer is given, so initialise the next box (i+1)
    applyToQuestionBox();
  });

}

// On load, this will be applied to question 0 (or initial 'i')
applyToQuestionBox();
```

It's a little bit annoying that you call the method again inside there, it means you have to read the flow of your code in chunks and makes it harder to reason about. The second option, though, is having a `for` loop to simply apply it all on page load, and never worry about it again:

```
const amountOfQuestions = 10;

for( const i = 0; i < amountOfQuestions; i++ ){
  
  $(".questionBox" + i + " .answerButton").click(function() {
    $(".questionBox" + i).hide();
    $(".questionBox" + (i + 1)).show();
    $(".answerButton").hide();
  });
  
}
```

This reads rather clearly what's going on there: ten questions, every one of them has a click, and every click has an effect. You can reason about this code.

Hope this clears up the issue you might have been having.

---

In purer JS (sorry I am more accustomed to it but would advise you to look into that instead of picking up jQuery - pure JS is much simpler now, and jQuery's usefulness is waning every year now). The setup here is to avoid having to predetermine the amount of questions. What if you add one to the HTML, do you want to *have* to go back to your javascript just to add a question? No, you want to automate this:

```js
// Let's select all question blocks
// It doesn't care if there's two or eight hundred
// It is important to store this in a variable though,
// as we will need to reference this list later to get the
// element after the current one thats displayed.
const questions = document.querySelectorAll( '.question' );

questions.forEach((question, index) => {
   
   // Attach an event listener to the internal button
   question.querySelector( 'button' ).addEventListener( 'click', event => {
      
      // Use CSS to hide and display certain elements
      question.classList.remove( 'active' );
  
      // Check if the next index exists, if not
      // we ran out of elements and have reached the end
      if( questions[ index + 1 ] ){
      
        questions[ index + 1 ].classList.add( 'active' );
      
      } else {
        
        alert( 'You completed all questions!' );
        
      }
    
   });
  
});
```

```css
.question { display: none; }
.question.active { display: block; }
```

```html
<section class="question active">
  <p>Question 1</p>
  <button>Answer</button>
</section>

<section class="question">
  <p>Question 2</p>
  <button>Answer</button>
</section>

<section class="question">
  <p>Question 3</p>
  <button>Answer</button>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it solved! The problem was that the selector in the function call is kind of static, it did not increment after the first time in the below code.

```
let i = 0;

$(".questionBox" + i + " .answerButton").click(function() {
  $(".questionBox" + i).hide();
  i++;
  $(".questionBox" + i).show();
  $(".answerButton").hide();
});
```

It works when i only increment inside of the function:

```
   $(".answerButton").click(function() {
      $(".questionBox"+i).hide();
      i++;
      $(".questionBox"+i).show();
      $(".answerButton").hide();
   });
```

Comment: Actually, your solution is not what you think it is. It only works because you changed your initial selector to _all answerButtons_, and then applied the click to _every one of them_. Where you increment didn't actually solve the issue, what you bound the click to did.